# How to write xpath for logout?

Tags: xpath, selenium

Here is the code for text 'logout' :

```
tr>
<td valign="middle" align="center">
<a href="logout">
<p class="iconLabel">Logout</p>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried with `//a[text()='logout']/@href` , but saying as not found. How can i write the actual path ?

Here is the code for symbol 'logout' :

```
<td width="60px" valign="middle" align="center">
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" align="center">
<img width="40px" height="40px" align="absmiddle" src="open/css/images/app/logout.png">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPATH

```
//a[//text()='Logout']/@href
```

### Result:

```
logout
```

Comment: Above syntax is correct.Actually, there is an image & text to logout, separately. Above code is for text. Command executes fine without error in Selenium IDE but it doesn't reflect in UI. Should i need to post the code for corresponding image aswell ?

Comment: @JackieJames: It follows from your comments that you haven't provided the real XML document. Asking how to select a node without providing the real XML document is like asking: "What will be the weather today" but not saying where you are located.

Answer (score 0):

XPath queries are case sensitive. So if a link has the title of "Logout", an XPath query looking for "logout" won't find it.

Since you seem to be using Selenium, you can get the logout image itself by using this CSS selector:

```
img[src*='logout.png']
```

Or this XPath:

```
//img[contains(@src, 'logout.png')]
```